# Is there a way when using WIFI to know the specific users computer ids?

Tags: privacy, wifi

When you use WIFI is there a way to know the other users computer ids and MAC addresses? What other WIFI users can know about you when you share same WIFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By computer ID, do you mean name/NETBIOS name?  This could be known, along with the MAC, a couple of different ways:

1. Using the AP software/webUI itself. The management console may already provide this information to you.
2. If you run switches that are fully manageable, you can track down what MAC addresses are connected to the port from which your AP is plugged into.
3. Third-party tools and software could also provide this information for hosts that are connected to your network.

Anyone connected to your AP would be able to run any number of networking tools to try and find information about the devices on the network. Once someone is connected to your network, they are able to then run attacks and reconnaissance against your network. So a knowledgable user could gain a substantial amount of data or do a lot of damage if your network is poorly designed or secured.